# Emulsion formation during extraction

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

While extracting benzoic acid from ether with $\ce{NaOH}$ solution, an emulsion forms between the layers. On the other hand, when aniline is extracted from ether with $\ce{HCl}$ the separation proceeds smoothly. Why does the emulsion form in the former case?